# How does LSTM cell map to layers?

Tags: lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm having trouble understanding exactly the scope of an LSTM cell --how it maps to a network's layers. From Graves (2014):

Seems to me that in a single-layered network the layer = lstm cell. How does this actually work in a multilayered rnn?

**Three-layer RNN**
[image: Three Layer RNN]

**LSTM Cell**
[image: LSTM Cell]

The output of the cell is *h_t* with no superindex indicating a specific layer. Same thing with the equations. Does each cell span across a single layer? Or does each cell span across the entire three nodes at each time step?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each node with name `h` in Figure 1 represents one LSTM cell. Note that `h_{t-1}`, `h{t}` and `h{t+1}` with the same superindex are the same cell. They are just unrolled in time. However, different superindices represent different LSTM cells.

The input of a cell with superindex 2 or 3 is not just the data sample `x` but also output of the previous cell.

You are correct. A single-layered RNN network consists of one LSTM cell. In the multi-layer RNN case, input of an intermediate LSTM cell is output of the previous LSTM cell. In Figure 1, the data sample `x` is also fed along with the LSTM output.

Comment: In that same paper (p. 7) he states "the network architecture was a single hidden layer with 1000 LSTM units". Is the right way to interpret this a single layer with 1000 neurons?